# Lost files on upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, data-recovery, partial-upgrade

I used a usb stick to upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04. Now I can't find my files - downloads, pictures etc. empty. Tried to backup but ran out of drive memory, so guess they must be still on the drive. I may have put the wrong user name into the upgrade box. How can I restore my files?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't erased everything while upgrading?

Comment: You did not make a backup before upgrading? What is the relation between your memory and the drive? I don't understand

Comment: Raphael,If I had erased everything the disk would have had plenty of space for the backup.

Comment: don.joey, I did make a backup before upgrading, but when I tried to restore the backup it did restore quite a bit, but ran out of drive memory, so I assume form this that the files are still on the drive, but maybe under a different user name.

Answer (score 0):

If you did use the wrong username which seems the case considering your comments proceed as follows:

**Step 1**

Open a terminal by holding CTRL and ALT and tapping T in the terminal enter the command `gksu nautilus`

[image: sudo nautilus]

**Step 2** Click File System on the left side of the window
[image: sudo nautilus]

and then click to open Home

[image: home]

If what you surmise is true you should find your files within the folder that has the same name as *your* old username

[image]

Comment: If my answer worked for you please upvote/accept it so that others may benefit from your experience. Thank you!